# Get 100 rows with maximum of 10 rows per group

Tags: mysql, database, select

I have the following query, and I would like to get 100 items from the database, but `host_id` is in the `urls` table many times, and I would like to get a maximum of 10 unique rows from that table per `host_id`.

```
select *
from urls
join hosts using(host_id)
where
(
    last_run_date is null
    or last_run_date <= date_sub(curdate(), interval 30 day)
)
and ignore_url != 1
limit 100
```

So, I would like:

- Maximum Results = 100
- Max Rows Per Host = 10

I am not sure what I would need to do to accomplish this task. Is there a way to do this without a subquery?

## Hosts Table

```
CREATE TABLE `hosts` (
    `host_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `host` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `last_fetched` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `ignore_host` TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`host_id`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `host` (`host`)
)
```

## Urls Table

```
CREATE TABLE `urls` (
    `url_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `parent_url_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `scheme` VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
    `host_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `path` VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,
    `query` VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,
    `date_found` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `last_run_date` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `ignore_url` TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`url_id`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `host_path_query` (`host_id`, `path`, `query`)
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Thats it** (I hope)

I cant test i real. i have no data. pls test it and give me a little ping.

```
SELECT *
  FROM (
    SELECT
      @nr:=IF(@lasthost = host_id, @nr+1, 1) AS nr,
      u.*,
      @lasthost:=IF(@lasthost = host_id, @lasthost, host_id) AS lasthost  
      FROM
        urls u,
         ( SELECT @nr:=4, @lasthost:=-1 ) AS tmp
      WHERE (
            last_run_date IS NULL
            OR last_run_date <= date_sub(curdate(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
      )
      AND ignore_url != 1
      ORDER BY host_id, last_run_date
  ) AS t
  LEFT JOIN HOSTS USING(host_id)
  WHERE t.nr < 11
  LIMIT 100;
```

**ok,**

**first:**

I only select the rows with your query, and order it
by the host_id and time

```
SELECT
      u.*
      FROM
        urls u
         ( SELECT @nr:=4, @lasthost:=-1 ) AS tmp
      WHERE (
            last_run_date IS NULL
            OR last_run_date <= date_sub(curdate(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
      )
      AND ignore_url != 1
      ORDER BY host_id, last_run_date
```

**second**

I add to variables **nr** and **lasthost** and setup it in the select. Now
i count nr each row and reset it to 1 if the host_id is change. So i get a
list of rows numbert from 1 to n for each host_id

SELECT
  @nr:=IF(@lasthost = host_id, @nr+1, 1) AS nr,
  u.*,
  @lasthost:=IF(@lasthost = host_id, @lasthost, host_id) AS lasthost
  FROM
    urls u,
     ( SELECT @nr:=4, @lasthost:=-1 ) AS tmp
  WHERE (
        last_run_date IS NULL
        OR last_run_date <= date_sub(curdate(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
  )
  AND ignore_url != 1
  ORDER BY host_id, last_run_date

**third**

i put it this query in a new select so i can join your second table and restrict the result only for rows  less 11 and also limit the result to 100

```
SELECT *
  FROM (
    SELECT
      @nr:=IF(@lasthost = host_id, @nr+1, 1) AS nr,
      u.*,
      @lasthost:=IF(@lasthost = host_id, @lasthost, host_id) AS lasthost  
      FROM
        urls u,
         ( SELECT @nr:=4, @lasthost:=-1 ) AS tmp
      WHERE (
            last_run_date IS NULL
            OR last_run_date <= date_sub(curdate(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
      )
      AND ignore_url != 1
      ORDER BY host_id, last_run_date
  ) AS t
  LEFT JOIN HOSTS USING(host_id)
  WHERE t.nr < 11
  LIMIT 100;
```

**Thats all**

Comment: Seems to work... could you please explain what is happening in the answer as well?

Comment: i have added it to my answer

Answer (score 0):

So you need a limited `JOIN`. Another guess:

```
SELECT * FROM hosts
LEFT JOIN urls ON
       urls.host_id = hosts.host_id
WHERE urls.host_id IN
      (SELECT host_id FROM urls
      LIMIT 0,10)
LIMIT 0,100
```

Comment: That doesn't seem very optimal, there are more than 10 hosts in the hosts table, so I would have to do `order by rand()` which is very slow.

Comment: I assumed that you want just 10 diffrent hosts which are already ordered by ID or sth. Maybe you can give an example of your tables in you question. EDIT: ah, I See I misunderstood your question...

Comment: Please post wich field are in wich table is and the datatype

Comment: I do want 10 different hosts, but there are more than 10 hosts in the hosts table. Your query will select the first 10 hosts an never anything else. So if there are 10,000 hosts, the query will only select the first 10 every time.